# Wolfram Alpha doesn't give right eigenvalues?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, wolfram-alpha

I used [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%3D0.35,%20b%3D0.5,%20eigenvectors((%7B%7B1%20-%20a,%200,%20(1%20-%20a)%20b,%200%7D,%20%7Ba,%200,%20a%20b,%200%7D,%20%7B0,%201%20-%20a,%20(1%20-%20a)%20(1%20-%20b),%20(1%20-%20a)%20b%20%7D,%20%7B0,%20a,%20a%20(1%20-%20b),1-%20(1-%20a)b%7D%7D))) to calculate the eigenvectors of the matrix

$$
A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1-a & 0 & (1-a)b & 0\\
     a & 0 & ab & 0\\
    0 & 1-a & (1-a)(1-b) & (1-a)b\\
    0 & a & a(1-b) & 1-(1-a)b
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

for $a=0.35, b=0.5$ with the command

> a=0.35, b=0.5, eigenvectors(({{1 - a, 0, (1 - a) b, 0}, {a, 0, a b, 0}, {0, 1 - a, (1 - a) (1 - b), (1 - a) b }, {0, a, a (1 - b),1- (1- a)b}}))

It gives what I think is the correct result in the result section: $(0.513344, 0.276416, 0.552832, 0.595357)$ (the vector of which I'm interested) but in the eigenvalue section there's $\lambda_1 = -1.3033$ and not $1$ as I expected.
 Also, in the eigenvectors section, there isn't the vector given in the result (or its multiple), what's up with that?

[Other software](http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/calculate.aspx) give the eigenvalue $1$ and the same eigenvector. Here's the matrix for input there if somebody wants to check

> 0.650 0.000 0.325 0.000
>
> 0.350 0.000 0.175 0.000
>
> 0.000 0.650 0.325 0.325
>
> 0.000 0.350 0.175 0.675

I have checked and double-checked and still get this weird output from Wolfram Alpha.

PS. If I change the command to eigenvalues, then it gives $1.$ and also other eigenvalues correctly (up to a precision). So clearly this is an error in WA.

Comment: why should the result to be not right?

Comment: i can compute the Eigenvalues with Maple

Comment: When I enter merely `a=0.35, b=0.5, {{1 - a, 0, (1 - a) b, 0}, {a, 0, a b, 0}, {0, 1 - a, (1 - a) (1 - b), (1 - a) b }, {0, a, a (1 - b),1- (1- a)b}}` into WA, it lists an eigenvalue of $1$. So it can compute the correct eigenvalue, but somehow the "eigenvector" function call doesn't behave as expected.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $1$ should be an eigenvalue, since this is a stochastic matrix and also other software (and even WA if we change the command to 'eigenvalues') give the eigenvalue $1$ with that same eigenvector. Yes please, if you check with Maple, we have even more confirmation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That's my experience as well.

Comment: Probably nobody here can answer the "what's up with that" question - just report it to Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: If you scroll down to the "Jordan Decomposition," it is clearly decomposing the wrong matrix.

Comment: i have got $$0,1,\frac{13}{40}-\frac{\sqrt{91}}{40},\frac{13}{40}+\frac{\sqrt{91}}{40}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner With what input to Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: not in WA, this is the Maple input

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Then why do you think the correct values are helpful? The question is, why does WA get it wrong, and presumably, how to get WA to do the right thing.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I reported it, just wanted to be sure It is an error first and not just something I made wrong.

Comment: [Thomas Andrews's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2332609#comment-4802147) comes closest to an answer I think.

Comment: PS. Just noticed it can solve it for general $a$ and $b$ correctly as well. (I put in the values before when I had error in the matrix and it didn't give a nice solution.)

Comment: I'm not getting this issue at all using those commands on that matrix, I wonder what could be the issue

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I already tried that. Still get the wrong eigenvalues, now $\lambda_1=-9.43808$ (and wrong matrix $M$ in the Diagonalization section). But as I mentioned, if I leave setting the values out, WA gives the correct general solution for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @ploosu2. I agree with you; I tried different things and deleted my comment. Sorry for that !

Answer (score 0):

*This is too long for a comment.*

When we look at the characteristic polynomial given by Wolfram Alpha when asking for the eigenvectors (entering $a=\frac 7 {20}$ and $b=\frac 12$), it is reported to be
$$\lambda^4+\frac{9}{2} \sqrt{\frac{13}{7}} \lambda^3+\frac{1355 }{588}\lambda^3-\frac{1501}{588}
   \sqrt{\frac{13}{7}} \lambda^2-\frac{845}{147}\lambda^2+\frac{319 }{196}\lambda-\frac{319
   }{98}\sqrt{\frac{13}{7}}$$ the solutions of which being effectively $$\{ -9.43808, 1.15923, -0.0790194-0.631825 i,
   -0.0790194+0.631825 i\}$$ but they are **not the same** as those obtained when entering $a=0.35$ and $b=0.5$.

The characteristic polynomial should be 
$$\lambda ^4-\frac{33 }{20}\lambda ^3+\frac{559 }{800}\lambda ^2-\frac{39 
   }{800}\lambda$$ obtained from the general case and replacing $a$ and $b$ by their rational values; the solutions of this last polynomial being
$$\left\{ 0, 1, \frac{13-\sqrt{91}}{40}
   , \frac{13+\sqrt{91}}{40}
   \right\}$$ More than strange, for sure.